# How can I open a specific database on Google Firestore in Python?

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firebase and setting/retrieving documents from Firestore with this code:

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials, firestore

cred = credentials.ApplicationDefault()
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, options={"projectId": "huq-jimbo"})
firestore_client = firestore.client()
doc = firestore_client.collection(f"example_collection").document("data")
print(doc)
```

I can only access the `(default)` database, and I can't see any way to open a different database.

Looking through the docs (e.g. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart) it seems there's no `database` parameter for `firestore.client()`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Multi-database support in Firestore is still in preview - I wouldn't be surprised if some client libraries don't support it yet. (For .NET we only released a beta *today* that supports it - we were planning on waiting until the feature had gone GA before releasing anything.)

Comment: Having said that, it's in this code: https://github.com/googleapis/python-firestore/blob/main/google/cloud/firestore_v1/client.py

Comment: And it's listed here: https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/firestore/latest/client

Comment: @JonSkeet Docs say "For now, DEFAULT_DATABASE (the default value) is the only valid database" though, so it indeed looks like the Python clients haven't been updated yet.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen: It's interesting that that doc doesn't have the updated version of the comment from [this PR](https://github.com/googleapis/python-firestore/pull/753). I suspect it's at least worth trying already :)